# Resources.Load возвращает null

Tags: c#, unity3d

Необходимо изменить спрайт на кнопке,однако при загрузке спрайта с помощью Resources.Load спрайт полностью исчезает,сам загружаемый спрайт лежит в папке Resources.Как это можно исправить?Код:

```
[SerializeField]
    Button but;
but.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Malt.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
 using UnityEngine.UI;

public class qwertyui : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    Button but;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        but.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load ("Malt", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
}
```

Если не помогло, то ОЧЕНЬ внимательно сравните имя спрайта с тем, что вы написали, и не менее внимательно посмотрите, как назвали папку Resources (могут быть ошибки). Еще проверьте, лежит ли Resources в Assets (нет ли "между ними" еще папок)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Source Image компонента Image
Image sourceImage;
// Поле скрипта (просто для наглядности)
public Sprite scriptSprite;

void Start() {
    sourceImage = GetComponent<Image>();
    scriptSprite = Resources.Load("Sword", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
}

void Update() {
    // Жмакая раз в ПРОБЕЛ картинка появляется
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)) {
        sourceImage.sprite = scriptSprite;
    }
}
```

**Krem Soda**, премного благодарен!!!!